# Ajax: PHP Echo is empty

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem. I want to get the value from my PHP file. If I make an echo in my JS file, I get an empty value. How do I get the value from my PHP file?
The ajaxComplete function is called. The if-statement in the ajax-method is also executed but i dont get the boolean-value $email_error, that was set in the test.php file.

functions.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#mail-email").val();
        $(".form-check").load("test.php", {
            email: email
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
          var test = "<?php echo $email_error; ?>";
    if(test==true) {
        $("#mail-email").addClass("input-error");
    }
  });
});
```

test.php

```
<?php

$email_error = false;
 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    
        if(empty($_POST["email"])) {
        echo "<span>- E-Mail Required</span></br>";
        $email_error = true;
    } 
   }
?>
```

Comment: `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,xhr,options){`

Comment: You should also be validating the required form field on the client-side to avoid meaningless trips to your server.  This should not replace the server-side validation, but added as an earlier layer of validation.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. But regards to the ajaxComplete-Function: It works properly. Everything is executed. But i dont get the value from my php file

Comment: How exactly do you know that your `ajaxComplete()` call is delivering you the echoed string from the actual ajax call? It looks like whenever the ajax call resolves (no matter what is returned) you have hardcoded `<?php echo $email_error; ?>` which is NOT coming from the ajax call but is coming from the initial page load.  Ajax can only receive what is printed from `test.php`. This will either be the html or nothing at all.  This is why your `true` _works_. It is by coincidence.  Your `$email_error = true|false;` is definitely not making its way back with the response.

Comment: If you want to pass multiple pieces of data back from the php script, then echo a json string.  `echo json_encode(['error' => true, 'message' => 'E-Mail Required']);` then use those object properties in your js to update your html.

Comment: I am completely new to php/js/css etc.
I thought I only have one ajax call, so my ajax-complete-method is triggered for this one ajax-call only. I also used `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<?php echo $email_error; ?>";` to see if ajax-complete is called. It was called because my original text was replaced with an empty string. Okay, I will then call it with 
`echo json_encode(['error' => true, 'message' => 'E-Mail Required'])` and also implement the client-side validation.

Comment: One more question, could there be security problems when I write the code from the ajax-complete method to the php file? Or is that not a good programming style? Because I tried it before i asked the question. And there was no problem with echo-call or adding a class

Comment: Something like: `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(function(event,xhr,options){
    if(options.error) {
        $("#mail-email").addClass("input-error");  
        $("#test").html =  options.message; }
  });` (untested)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I appreciate it.